# Can I call start_item on a virtual sequencer

Tags: uvm

Lets say I have a virtual sequence (vseq) connected to a virtual sequencer (vsqr) which instantiates two physical sequencers (psqr1, psqr2). These two physical sequencers work on the same sequence item but an element in the sequence item differentiates which sequencer to use. I have to call start_item() on a sequence item and I can not start the virtual sequence. Is it possible to call the start_item on the sequence_item and let the virtual sequencer put that to the relevant physical sequencer based on the sequence_item randomization?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using `uvm_do_on_with. 
Here you can randomize sequence items in virtual sequence, and pass that to corresponding sequencer based on element which you have.

But note that, for this , you have to make sure that item is not again randomize in physical sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what do you want, but checking the implementation of [this](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1b/html/files/seq/uvm_sequencer_base-svh.html#uvm_sequencer_base.execute_item) function might help you.